# Cannot access a shared folder on windows server 2012 R2 from a 2008 R2 machine

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012, network-share

I have setup a simple shared folder on my windows 2012 R2 machine (Azure).  It's not on a domain but I can connect to it from both windows 8 and another server 2012 machine without any problems.

When I try to connect from windows server 2008 R2 however I cannot get past the network password prompt.

I've tried MYSERVER\testaccount (the default) and WORKGROUP\testaccount and COMPUTERNAME\testaccount  (all machines have the same default WORKGROUP name.)

I'm connecting over using  \mycloud.cloudapp.net\backup  which appears to be working ok,  I've created endpoints for Ports 445UDP/TCP on the azure portal and disabled the windows firewall for testing.

I'm not sure what's left to try.

Comment: To clarify, you've tried W2K12R2ServerName\Username?

Comment: Yes I have with no success.